# Been at this awhile

Tags: bash, character, jq

So I have a json file converted from xml. I'm trying to use jq in a bash script to work through this problem.

current at command line `jq -r '.users.user[0].id."#text"' cosmology18.json` works great and shows the output perfect

however in bash i've had to use substitutions to try to get this to work with no resolve.

first I got part of it to work the first part to read user data

```
  baselineresult=$(jq -r '.users.user[1].cpid."#text"' $1)
```

would allow me to echo out the data received perfectly

however when i try to add `$basecount` which increases each time i couldn't get it to work so i constructed this crazy method in which I had to use substitutions to get the $basecount into the [ ] of the user.

```
  bracea="["
  braceb="]"
  dquote='"'
  squote="'"
  pound="#"
  echo test of command is jq -r "${squote}.users.user${bracea}${basecount}${braceb}.cpid.${dquote}#text${dquote}${squote} $1"

  baselineresult=$(jq -r "${squote}.users.user${bracea}${basecount}${braceb}.cpid.${dquote}${pound}text${dquote}${squote} $1")
  echo $baselineresult
```

the command matches the one i entered at command line to work.

however i get this:

test of command is jq -r '.users.user[0].cpid."#text"' cosmology18.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
'.users.user[0].cpid."#text"' cosmology18.json
jq: 1 compile error

any ideas.. been at this for 8 hours now. 
I can't seem to find this illegal character as the output is identical to the one id use at command line of jq -r '.users.user[0].id."#text"' cosmology18.json

Comment: sorry i typoed a echo above                       echo test of command is jq -r "${squote}.users.user${bracea}${basecount}${braceb}.cpid.${dquote}${pound}text${dquote}${squote} $1"                also note ive tried even with out all the subtitutions and still having a hell of a time for the jq to accept what bash has sent it which outputs properly. so its not bash but somethign with jq

Comment: Can you fix this line "first I got part of it to work the first part to read user data?"

Comment: Can you explain what you want the script to do, perhaps in pseudocode?

Comment: It would also be helpful to include sample input

Comment: well when i ran baselineresult=$(jq -r '.users.user[0].cpid."#text"' cosmology18.json) it gave me the cpid and i cud echo it out..

when i tried to substitute so i can increment the [0] in the loop itd always fail its something to do with [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't know what's `bash` syntax and what's `jq` syntax, so you're merging them both together.

Here's an example of what `jq` expects:

```
.users.user[1].cpid."#text"
```

Here's what you're giving it:

```
'.users.user[1].cpid."#text"' filename
```

`jq` is never supposed to see the single quotes, in your working command they're bash syntax to specify which string to pass to `jq`. Instead, you try to give single quotes to `jq` which has no idea what that means.

Similarly, the space followed by the filename is bash syntax to specify that you want to pass a second argument. Instead, you try to give them to `jq` in its first argument, which it does not expect.

To `jq`, this command is indistinguishable from your original (it results in an `execve` call with the exact same parameters). You can vary the variable to get different indices:

```
var=1
baselineresult=$(jq -r '.users.user['"$var"'].cpid."#text"' "$1")
```

Comment: root@iFoggz-s1:~/Downloads/snapshots/converted# jq -r '.users.user[0].cpid."#text"' cosmology18.json 
e64c6f0a50af958349a03ee08ab178f7

is what id get in terminal but i will try to tinker with it to the examples u have shown

Comment: ur right i removed the ${squote} aka ' and it worked. thank u so much im sure 95% of my hair is remaining!